# I want to change the .name of an uploaded filein Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, quasar-framework

So I have this file input where the user selects an image. But once I have this image, I want to change ONLY the name, so for example, user uploads "wallpaper_hd_dragonball_z.jpg" and I want it to be named "wallpaper.jpg". This is the input:

```
<input type="file" @change="uploadImage($event,userDetails.email)">
```

And this is the function it calls to store the image in the database:

```
uploadImage(e, email){
  this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(this.selectedFile.name);
  var storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref(`profilePics/${email}/${this.selectedFile.name}`);
  const task = storageRef.put(this.selectedFile);

  task.on('state_changed',snapshot=>{
    let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
    this.uploadValue = percentage;
  }, error=>{console.log(error.message)},
  ()=>{this.uploadValue=100;
    task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
      this.picture = url;
      console.log(this.picture);
    })
  })
}
```

Basically what I'm trying is:

```
  this.selectedFile.name = "profPic.jpg";
  console.log(this.selectedFile.name);
```

But it doesn't work. I've looked around google and I can't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to change the name of the file you have in memory, because the name property of a File object is read-only.

Instead, just rename the file you will save in Firebase Storage.

```
function getFileExtension(fileName) {
  return filename.split('.').pop();
}

//...
  const fileExtension = getFileExtension(this.selectedFile.name);
  var storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref(`profilePics/${email}/wallpaper.${fileExtension}`);
  storageRef.put(this.selectedFile);
  // ...
```

Or create a new file object, with another name.

```
const myNewFile = new File([this.selectedFile], 'wallpaper.png', {type: myFile.type});
firebaseApp.storage().ref(`profilePics/${email}/${myNewFile.name}`);
storageRef.put(myNewFile);
// ...
```